# fftw in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, fftw

I'm trying to link my project with fftw and so far, I've gotten it to compile, but not link. As the site said, I generated all the .lib files (even though I'm only using double precision), and copied them to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib`, the .h file to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include` and the .dll to `C:\windows\system32`.

I've copied the tutorial program, and the exact error I am getting is:

```
1>hw10.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftw_free referenced in function "bool __cdecl test(void)" (?test@@YA_NXZ)
1>hw10.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftw_destroy_plan referenced in function "bool __cdecl test(void)" (?test@@YA_NXZ)
1>hw10.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftw_execute referenced in function "bool __cdecl test(void)" (?test@@YA_NXZ)
1>hw10.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftw_plan_dft_1d referenced in function "bool __cdecl test(void)" (?test@@YA_NXZ)
1>hw10.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftw_malloc referenced in function "bool __cdecl test(void)" (?test@@YA_NXZ)
```

So, what could be wrong with my project setup? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually linked against the library in the project you're building?

```
Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies
```

You need to add the library's filename to that field.

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting it to be something simple like that.

Answer (score 5):

My case

Using [`FFTW`](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html) in Visual Studio 2010

Precompiled FFTW 3.3.1 Windows DLLs install using fftw-3.2.1-dll.zip, on my Windows XP machine.

1. Open `cmd` window and go to `lib.exe` folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin>`
2. Type `lib /def:libfftw3-3.def`
3. Type `lib /def:libfftw3f-3.def`
4. Type `lib /def:libfftw3l-3.def`
5. If you have a error on command, copy any `mspdb80.dll` or `mspdb100.dll` file to in bin directory.
6. You will get 6 files

   > libfftw3-3.exp, libfftw3-3.lib, libfftw3f-3.exp, libfftw3f-3.lib,
   >   libfftw3l-3.exp and libfftw3l-3.lib

   and copy it to programming directory.
7. Delete all `mspdb80.dll` or `mspdb100.dll` file from bin directory.
8. Closed Project and open again and rebuild it again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've actually linked your project against the lib and it doesn't work, use `/verbose:lib` and paste the output of that and the output of

```
dumpbin /exports fftw.lib | findstr fftw_free
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.  What helped was compiling the fftw libs with this help [Compiling FFTW source in Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833852/compiling-fftw-source-in-visual-studio). Actually more closely the problem was compiling my application Win 32 and trying to use x64 -libraries. So make sure the platform is same.

Comment: I used the fftw windows binaries **prebuilt for 32bit** without building them myself and it worked. What helped was your hint that I was building my app in 32bit mode and using 64bit fftw. I'll also add that I use a 64bit Windows and that copying the fftw DLLs to `C:\Windows\System32` didn't work (i.e. my app didn't find them there). I had to copy them `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` for some reason.