# Compiling FFTW 3.3.4 With Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2013, fftw

Has anyone managed to compile the latest release of FFTW 3.3.4 using the Visual C++ compiler? I'm aware that the project maintainers offer pre-compiled dll's that were built with MinGW, but I'm looking to compile them myself.

So far, I've downloaded the source (of course), and I am trying to use one of the pre-made VS solutions that was reported to work for Visual Studio 2010 and FFTW 3.3, but when I'm building, I'm getting a few "unresolved external" errors like the following:

```
Error   1259    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _fftwf_mkprinter_str referenced in function _fftwf_export_wisdom_to_string    C:\Users\bryan\Downloads\fftw-3.3.4\fftw-3.3.4\fftw-3.3-libs\libfftwf-3.3\export-wisdom-to-string.obj   libfftwf-3.3
```

I know this is a bit of a stretch, but has anyone built FFTW 3.3.4 using Visual Studion 2013?

Comment: For me, it was missing Windows7.1SDK. Then I tried to install that but realised that first I have to remove Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) and (x64), than install the SDK and then install again the packages. No it says: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.targets(146,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515.`

I heard that it is not a must to install the SDK but it is possible to change the platform toolset to Visual Studio 2010 (v100).

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem.
Take a look on
http://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin_SDK_%28MSVC_2013%29
There is explained how you can build libfftw-3.3
In the same way you can build libfftwf-3.3

To build bench and benchf you have to remove '....\libbench2\aligned-main.c'
That is explained here (commentar 6)
[Compiling FFTW source in Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833852/compiling-fftw-source-in-visual-studio)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.