# Using single precision floating-point with FFTW in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, fftw

I am trying to use the [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) library in a Visual Studio project, and I am having trouble with getting the floating point precision to work. I have created the library files and linked them as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727293/fftw-in-visual-studio) and I have only included the libfftw3f-3.lib library as it says in their [documentation](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html), and everything else is fine except for the `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d()` function. It will not accept my array of type float* for parameter 3 because it is incompatible with its argument of type double*. I understand it is just precision but, I would prefer to use floating point because fftw does support it, and b/c of the way I am `memcpy()` 'ing data from a float array. I am just having issues with fftw library using floating point. I havent seen anything specific on this in their Windows section like in their Unix section besides linking to the `libfftw3f-3.lib` library. Can anyone give me clues on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For single precision routines in FFTW you need to use routines with an `fftwf_` prefix rather than `fftw_`, so your call to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d()` should actually be `fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d()`.